# 2022 Mathleague Target Round question 8

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

I participated in the 2022 Mathleague Middle school competition, and I was presented the following problem as the last question on the Target Round: "If $x$ is equal to the estimate of $\frac{n}{60}$ (rounded to the nearest tenth), for how many n is $x>\frac{n}{60}$ for $n<2021?$" I made a pattern, (the change between each of the numbers $n$ where $x>\frac{n}{60}$ is $1,1,2,2,3,3,...$) but I don't know how that would help in find the answer.

Comment: the estimate of a number is the value after rounding?

Comment: Hi Kamal, could you perhaps share the pattern you found so we can give you the most personalized help? Welcome to the site btw

Comment: What does “the estimate” mean hear? Integer rounding?

Comment: @Buraian I shared the pattern. I've been here for a long time but my account mysteriously lost all of my progress in it, so I made a new one.

Answer (score 1):

We round up if the fractional part is greater than or equal to $\frac 12$.

If $x = 1$ the $x> n$ when $30\le n \le 59$ or $30$ values of $n$ when $1\le n\le 60$.

if $x = 2$ the $x> n$ when $90\le n \le 119,$ half the values of n in the interval $61\le n \le 120.$

How many complete 60 number intervals are there with $n < 2022$?

$2021 = 33\times 60 + 41$

And how many in the last interval?

Comment: Sorry I forgot that the question asked for rounding up to the nearest tenth.